# Make 2 sibling components talk to each other in Angular5

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm have started playing with angular and I'm trying to change the colors of my google maps when clicked one of the radio buttons (dark/light). The radio buttons are in one component and the map is in a different component. If I put the map and the radio buttons in the same component, then my app works the way I want, but when I have them in 2 different components the *ngIf doesn't detect the variable change.I have seen some links on how to make sibling components talk to each other, but honestly I don't know now if that's what I need or if it's correct to what I'm looking at
Map Component HTML

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"  [styles]="mapStyle === 'dark' ? styleDark : styleLight">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Map Component .ts

```
styleDark: any;
styleLight: any;
mapStyle: String;

...

constructor(public zone: NgZone, private styleService: VariablesService ){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.mapStyle = this.styleService.getStyleRadioButton();
    this.styleDark =   this.darkStyle;
    this.styleLight =  this.defaultStyle
}

public darkStyle = [
     ...
];

public defaultStyle = [];
```

Radio Buttons Component HTML

```
<label class="container">Dark
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" (click)='setMapStyle("dark")'>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Light
    <input type="radio" name="radio"  (click)='setMapStyle("light")'>
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Radio Button component .ts

```
...
constructor(private styleService : VariablesService, private mainMap: MainMapComponent) {}

setMapStyle(color) {
    this.styleService.setStyleRadioButton(color); 
    this.mapStyle = this.styleService.getStyleRadioButton();
    this.mainMap.ngOnInit(); //Trying to trigger the variables (the correct style gets trigger)
  }
```

Service file

```
...
    @Injectable()
    export class VariablesService {
      styleRadioButton: String = 'dark';
      constructor() { }

      setStyleRadioButton (color) {
        this.styleRadioButton = color;
      }

      getStyleRadioButton () {
        return this.styleRadioButton;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Create a service with an EventEmmitter, inject this service in both components. In the map component subscribe to the emitter and in the checkbox component emit the event.

Comment: Something to read: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data between n components it's easy with EventEmitter ...
You need a service to define the EventEmitter and the you can inject it in some components to listen to this event and in other components to emit events passing some data in it.

Service file

Define an EventEmitter to pass a String data ...

```
@Injectable()
export class VariablesService {

  mapStyleEmitter = new EventEmitter<String>();

}
```

Map component

Subscribe to the event

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone, private styleService: VariablesService ){
 this.styleService.mapStyleEmitter.subscribe(
            (style:String) => mapStyle = style;
        );

}
```

Radio button component

Emit the event with the data

```
...
constructor(private styleService : VariablesService, private mainMap:    MainMapComponent) {}

setMapStyle(color) {
    this.styleService.mapStyleEmitter.emit(color); 
}
```

Comment: that worked like a champ!! thanks so much. Do you know any good angular tutorial out there? I know there's the documentation from google but can be confusing to me sometimes and some udemy courses are very long